# NODE_ENV holds weird value

Tags: npm, gulp

I have this line in my `package.json`:

`set NODE_ENV=development; gulp clean && gulp build`

and when I execute the task the value of `ENV` is `development; gulp clean` and not just `development`

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following command
set NODE_ENV=development && gulp clean && gulp build
Replace ";" with "&&"

Comment: I have tried this and it works. Just a question: Is `development;` supposed to work or It really should be `development&&`?* Note that I placed && immediately after `development` because it is being read as `development<space>` and not as `development`

Comment: Yes It should not have any spaces